# Import from feed using a selector only if it has a given XML attribute

Tags: 8, importing-exporting

I'm working on an import from an RSS feed that includes two types of XML `<category>` elements:

- Subject Areas, e.g. `<category>Economics | Social and Behavioral Sciences</category>`
- Keywords, e.g. `<category domain="keywords">immigration, emigration, immigrants, international migration, poverty, immigration enforcement, asylum policy</category>`

I want to import the Keywords as their own taxonomy field. I can write the YAML as follows, but it predictably imports both Keywords and Subject Areas:

```
source:
  fields:
    -
      name: keywords
      label: Keywords
      selector: 'category'
process:
  field_keywords:
    -
      plugin: explode
      delimiter: ', '
      source: keywords
    -
      plugin: entity_generate
```

How do I adjust the selector so it only pulls from the `<category>` element that includes the `domain="keywords"` attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out with the help of an [XPATH cheatsheet](https://devhints.io/xpath) that shows how selectors I might have written to target HTML would transfer to XPATH values.

To only pull `<category domain="keywords">` items, I can use `category[@domain="keywords"]` as my selector. The other set of `<category>` items don't have a `domain` attribute, so I pulled them separately using the selector `category[not(@domain)]`.